Why does Visual Studio export a same class with different symbol?
I'm working on a dynamic library project using Visual Studio 2022. After I exported the library and tried to dynamically link it to my another program A, unresolved-external-symbol problems were raised. So I used Dependency Walker to see the symbols exported in the library.
Then I found what the problem is: the symbols in the library are different to the symbols produced from compilation of the program A while they are of one same class, and the difference is quite trivial:
This was produced from compilation of program A:
?onMouseWheel@DefaultViewController@Ext@@UEAAXAEB**U**GUIEventWheel@@@Z

while this was produced from compilation of the library:
?onMouseWheel@DefaultViewController@Ext@@UEAAXAEB**V**GUIEventWheel@@@Z 

Without very carefully checking letter by letter, you will not find where the difference is.
It's very strange as I use a same compiler - even the same solution - while it produces different symbols for identical member functions in two different project.
I don't know if there is any configuration what influences the symbol renaming process of VS2022.

Can you provide the definitions for this class and method?

Also, you may consider entering the symbols into a demangler to see the C++ declaration, e.g. http://demangler.com/, and seeing what the differences are.

Demangling your symbols with demangler.com, I get
public: virtual void __cdecl Ext::DefaultViewController::onMouseWheel(struct GUIEventWheel const & __ptr64) __ptr64
public: virtual void __cdecl Ext::DefaultViewController::onMouseWheel(class GUIEventWheel const & __ptr64) __ptr64

That is, in one definition you have a struct argument, and in the other, a class argument. Hopefully this helps you find the problem in your code.

Thank you for your help! I still don't know why these different name mangling for the same member function could happen though I make it work by declaring a new derived class DGUIEvent from GUIEvent and replace the GUIEvent argument with DGUIEvent, then there is no symbol-resolving error.

Thank you to @nneonneo for reminding me of the source of the error. Due to confidentiality, I cannot share the original code for this private project. However, I can outline its structure.
The classes GUIEventWheel are declared in a header file:
//GUIDefine.h
struct GUIEventWheel{...}


Definition of class DefaultViewController is as follows:
//DefaultViewController.h
class LIB DefaultViewController //LIB here will be __declspec(dllexport) or __declspec(dllimport) properly under different situations.
{
public:
    void onMouseWheel(const GUIEventWheel&){...}
}


Then I compile them and get a dynamic library.
In another project, I include both header files, and want to use instances of class DefaultViewController. Then when I build the project symbol-resolving error happens.
Upon realizing that the error was due to GUIEventWheel being treated as a class in the dynamic library project and as a struct in the project attempting to link it, which resulting in a minor difference in name mangling between the two projects, I resolved the issue by declaring an empty derived class of GUIEventWheel:
//DGUIEventWheel.h
class DGUIEventWheel:public GUIEventWheel{}


Then, I modified the definition of DefaultViewController::onMouseWheel to use this new class:
//new definition of DefaultViewController::onMouseWheel
class LIB DefaultViewController 
{
public:
    void onMouseWheel(const DGUIEventWheel&){...}
}

With this change, the symbol resolution error was resolved.
However, I remain uncertain as to why MSVC treats the parameter as a struct in one project and as a class in another.
